How can I fix my build fail issue, while taking --release build?
In my flutter application, I can't able to take the build. The build is failing.
I've executed the below command for taking build in my android mobile:
flutter build apk --release
By executing the above command, I'm getting this below error:
Font asset "BoxIcons.ttf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 320764 to 888 bytes (99.7% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when bu ilding your app. Font asset "Iconsax.ttf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 992800 to 2992 bytes (99.7% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when bu ilding your app.
Font asset "MaterialIcons-Regular.otf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 1645184 to 3440 bytes (99.8% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-ico ns flag when building your app.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':read_pdf_text:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
> Android resource linking failed
ERROR: /home/ruban/YAVAR/CLONE/prive_app/build/read_pdf_text/intermediates/merged_res/release/mergeReleaseResources/values/values.xml:194: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ lStar not found.
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
BUILD FAILED in 8s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
9.35

I'm using the flutter version of: Flutter 3.24.3 
Help me to fix this issue.

do you have multiple profiles/flavours in your project?

It happens because of outdated compileSdkVersion in read_pdf_text package you are using.
Fastest decision to solve this is to add another subprojects block in you build.gradle (the root one, not app/build.gradle) and up compileSdkVersion everywhere:
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {
        // Version must be 31 or newer, 34 here is just example because it is used by Flutter itself.
        compileSdkVersion 34
    }
}

Best decision is to switch to more modern package which dependencies are up-to-date.
